# Retrieving username attribute from Facebook friends list

Tags: android, facebook

I am retrieving id, name, username from Facebook friends list; it's working fine when using with Facebook application id "21484349....." and when am running same code with different facebook app id it is giving:

> com.facebook.android.FacebookError: (#100) Unknown fields: username.

The following is my code

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] requiredFields = new String[] { "id", "name", "username","installed" };
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
 parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
String jsonUser = null;
try {
jsonUser = mFacebook.request("me/friends",  parameters,"GET");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

return jsonUser;

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
if(result != null){
JSONObject obj;
try {
obj = Util.parseJson(result);
Log.i("json Response", obj.toString());
JSONArray array = obj.optJSONArray("data");     
if (array != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {                  
String name = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
String id = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
username = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("username");

}
}
}.execute();
```

When running this code it's working fine with one Application Id, but when I changed application id it's not working. I created application in Facebook developers and got an application id.

Comment: have you set HashKey for new facebook application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using v2.0 of the Graph API with one app, and the v1.0 with the other (working) one. In this version, the field `username` is no longer available, see:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> /me/username is no longer available.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/ (`username` not in the list of available fields)

Comment: Thanks for reply sir I hope your correct, but now how to change from v2.0 to v1.0 .

Comment: That will only help you until April 30th, 2015. Why do you specifically need the username?

Comment: If your app was created before 4/30/2014 you can add v1.0 in the url and you will do request against v1.0. If your app was created after that date you can not use v1.0.